# will_paginate rendering correct html but not displaying links

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

I am creating a web app in Ruby on Rails which pulls images from instagram and puts them into an array.

I have a initializer/config/will_paginate_array.rb with the line:

```
require "will_paginate/array"
```

My controller looks like this:

```
  def index
        result = []
        while result.length < 100
             //my logic here which adds a bunch of images to the array
             result.concat(data)
        end
        @results = result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 13)
  end
```

I am using this line in my html to render the links, but the links are not showing:

```
<%= will_paginate @results %>
```

To be clear, when I inspect element the markup is there(and all the pagination links are fully functional), it just isn't rendering/showing up on the page properly for some reason, and I am fairly sure it is not my css overriding anything.  The pagination div generated by will_paginate has a height and width of 0.  If I manually enter the next page for example localhost:3000?=2 it still advances the page correctly.

Perhaps it is some sort of compatibility issue with will_paginate and arrays?

Comment: You can use something like developer tools in chrome, or Firebug for FF to see why the div's height and width are 0. If it is a CSS issue, either of those tools should be able to point out the file that is giving them that size.

Comment: Thats the thing, I don't think its a css issue. The paginate div is being generated by the will_paginate gem, with a height and width of 0.  I have not personally attempted to style it in any way, and I have checked and rechecked the developer tools but I don't find any possible offenders.